# Not using NSMutableArray correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Im trying to inset data in to the array (temp) but for some reason it saves the same data over an over. I all ready checked the _singleSeismicInfo to verify that it was handling different data(you can see it in the double "/" printData method). So i know the problem is with the MutableArray.
Im new to iOS so if theres something Im not doing right let me know.

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [_httpContent getTextFromHTTP];

        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {

            NSString *line = _httpContent.lines[index];

            [_singleSeismicInfo fillSeismicInfo:line];
            //[_singleSeismicInfo printData];

            [temp addObject:_singleSeismicInfo];
        }
```

Comment: Do you think we can magically see what the printData method does?

Comment: you are adding the same object over and over (`_singleSeismicInfo`)... this is no bug in `NSMutableArray`

Comment: So you think you found a bug in something as essential as the array implementation, used billions of time every day… just think about it: is it more likely that Apple's engineers have made a mistake here or whether you have made a mistake? :-)

Comment: I'm adding the same object over and over but with different data inside it. _singleSeismicInfo is a data structure that gets fill with the fillSeismicInfo:line method.

Comment: a didn't add what it printed out because the data that prints out is correct and the only thing i need help with is with the "[temp addObject:_singleSeismicInfo]" method. The print data was for debugging.

Comment: If you add `_singleSeismicInfo` 10 times, and you change the data stored in `_singleSeismicInfo`, then you'll still have 10 times the same data. You are storing the same _instance_ over and over again.

Comment: Remember, a pointer to an object is like a sign _look here_. You are storing lots of pointers, but they all point to the very same place. And if you modify that object that was pointed to, no matter which pointer you follow you will always end up at the same object.

Comment: how is that? i change the data every time the for loop iterates.

Comment: Yes, but it changes the data inside the *same object*.

Comment: Obviously I don't think i found a bug. i made a mistake, thats why im here asking you guy's.

Comment: You should (probably) be creating a new instance of your object each time through the loop, and adding that new instance.

Comment: So what you saying is that, if I change the code so it makes a new object(_singleSeismicEvent) every time the for loop iterates, that should fix the problem?

Comment: @BenjaBoy: Exactly. (Well, depending on how your class is implemented, but most likely that is the solution.)

Comment: DarkDust thanks for the pointer reminder, forgot about that. Now i understand where's the problem. Wevah that is what i should do.

Comment: +1 if you think NSMutableArrays are nuts :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding `_singleSeismicInfo` over and over without ever reassigning a new object to the variable as far as I can see. So it's the same object over and over because that's what you add.

Comment: If you see in the code _singleSeismicInfo sends a message to fillSeismicInfo with a NSString(line) as parameter. that strings changes with the every iteration of the "_httpContent.lines[index]" inside the for loop.

Comment: Yes, but you're filling the same instance of SiesmicInfo (or whatever) over and over, so you'll end up with the last filled data a bunch of times.